# Change Swagger port in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swagger

I am unable to change the port that Swagger uses in docker compose. It works fine with regular docker, I simply set the -p argument on the run command. It seems that I should just need to set the ports field in the docker-compose file. But no matter what I try it just runs on 8080.

I am using the latest versions of docker and docker-compose. The docker image is called swaggerapi/swagger-ui. I have attempted setting the ports field for the container. Also tried setting the url variable in the swagger definition file. Tried changing the expose port. I tried with the docker-compose run command which lets you start an individual service and has the -p argument. Still nothing.

Ideally I should use this to build and run:

```
sudo docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

My compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:


  swagger:
    build: swagger
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - SWAGGER_JSON=/swagger.json

volumes:
  data:
    driver: "local"
```

And the docker file for the swagger service:

```
FROM swaggerapi/swagger-ui

EXPOSE 8081

COPY swagger.json /swagger.json

ENV SWAGGER_JSON "/swagger.json"
```

No matter what I do it wont change ports.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the port in your docker-compose file

```
swagger:
    build: swagger
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "8081:"**Port which you want to expose**"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - SWAGGER_JSON: /swagger.json
```

Comment: there are no equals in docker-compose for variable naming @Vimal